# Python: import and change canonical names in the current module

Tags: python, import, canonical-name

In a Python package directory of my own creation, I have an `__init__.py` file that says:

```
from _foo import *
```

In the same directory there is a _foomodule.so which is loaded by the above.  The shared library is implemented in C++ (using Boost Python).  This lets me say:

```
import foo
print foo.MyCppClass
```

This works, but with a quirk: the class is known to Python by the full package path, which makes it print this:

```
foo._foo.MyCppClass
```

So while `MyCppClass` exists as an alias in `foo`, `foo.MyCppClass` is not its canonical name.  In addition to being a bit ugly, this also makes `help()` a bit lame: `help(foo)` will say that foo contains a module `_foo`, and only if you say `help(foo._foo)` do you get the documentation for `MyCppClass`.

Is there something I can do differently in `__init__.py` or otherwise to make it so Python sees `foo.MyCppClass` as the canonical name?

I'm using Python 2.7; it would be great if the solution worked on 2.6 as well.

Comment: If the `_foo` module were written in Python, I'd just tell you to change your classes' `__module__` attribute (you could do this just after defining each class, or write a loop that does it all at once) but that attribute probably isn't writable on your C++ classes... Maybe there's some way to change that attribute in Boost? (Never used it myself.)

Comment: I think I can change the module name, but change it to what?  I don't want to go from `foo._foo.MyCppClass` to `foo.bar.MyCppClass` - I want to end up with just `foo.MyCppClass` as the canonical name in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  You can change the module name in your Boost.Python definition:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(_foo)
{
  scope().attr("__name__") = "foo";
  ...
}
```

The help issue is a separate problem.  I think you need to add each item to `__all__` to get it exported to help.

When I do both of these, the name of `foo.MyCppClass` is just that -- `foo.MyCppClass` -- and `help(foo)` gives documentation for `MyCppClass`.

Comment: Just setting `__name__` seems to solve it for me.  I tried to figure out a way to make it work entirely in the `__init__.py` file where I do `import *` but I didn't succeed.  Do you know if it's possible to set `__name__` in Python if I want to avoid changing the C++ code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the `help()` problem by adding the line

```
__all__ = ['MyCppClass']
```

to your `__init__.py` file.

Comment: That's an interesting point, so thank you.  However, I'm still looking for a solution to my "real" problem...fixing help() will be nice too though.